# Why is Autocomplete not working inside android.support.v7.widget.CardView Tag?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-cardview

I've tried almost all the solutions available online, but this problem hasn't gone away.
I've tried:
- invalidate caches/ Restart
- restart android studio and my laptop
- rebuild project
- refresh gradle

But nothing has worked.
Is there any other way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Have you got the following in your root node :

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

For example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete your project .iml files and .idea folder and import project again.
Also make sure only one project is open in Android Studio when you are doing this.

Comment: I found the .idea file but where is the .iml one?

Comment: OK I did that but it just made the problem worse, now I don't even get a suggestion for the tag, I have to type the entire thing!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the right thing to do but i created a class by extending the cardview class -

```
public class ArticleCardView extends CardView{
    public ArticleCardView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ArticleCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ArticleCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }
}
```

And then in the `xml` i replaced the `android.support.v7.widget.CardView` with my custom class (`ArticleCardView`).

Auto complete started working .